# Permissions on files uploaded using AWS iOS SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading files to an S3 bucket using a method based on the AWS example code here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

The problem is, once those files are uploaded, the default permission to view those files is only given to the owner of the S3 bucket, and I would like them to be publicly available.  How can I achieve this using the iOS SDK 2.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign `AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead` to the [`ACL`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3PutObjectRequest.html#//api/name/ACL) property on your `AWSS3PutObjectRequest` object.

Comment: This works using the AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest ACL property in SDK 2